# SQLite Python does not insert

Tags: python, sqlite

I am working on a project in which I am using python to store sensor data in a SQLite Database.

If the table does not exists it will be created like this:

```
query_db('create table if not exists %s (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, value double, datetimestamp DATETIME, user CHAR(2));' % (sensor_name+'_VALUES'))
```

Next I want to insert the values from a HTTP Post Request:

```
  sensor_value = request.json['value']
        dtstamp = request.json['timestamp']
        user_name = request.json['user']
        result = query_db('INSERT INTO %s  ("value", "datetimestamp", "user") VALUES ( "%s" ,"%s" , "%s");' % (sensor_name + '_VALUES', sensor_value, dtstamp, user_name))
```

But I don't get an error and it also seems like the insert is not executed.
The request looks like this:

```
{
    "value" : 22,
    "timestamp" : "2017-02-17 22:22:22",
    "user" : "TE"
}
```

Anyone know why?

Comment: Solved it - but why do you have to commit on Inserts? DDL Statements just work -.-

Answer (score 1):

You need to *commit the transaction to persist the changes in the database*:

```
db.commit()
```

Here is some additional information about why and when do you need to commit:

- [python sqlite3, how often do I have to commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36243538/771848)